External scripts not loaded in symfony 7 with symfony ux
I am currently using symfony with many packages of symfony ux, and my external scripts (such as font awesome or google fonts) are not loaded, i receive this error message : Content-Security-Policy : Les paramètres de la page ont empêché l’exécution d’un script intégré (script-src-elem) car il enfreint la directive suivante : « script-src 'self' »
Here is my composer.json :
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.2",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "api-platform/core": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.11",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.17",
        "gocardless/gocardless-pro": "^5.9",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "*",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.25",
        "symfony/asset": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/asset-mapper": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/console": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/intl": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/mime": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/process": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/stimulus-bundle": "^2.13",
        "symfony/string": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/translation": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/ux-turbo": "^2.13",
        "symfony/validator": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "7.0.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php82": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "importmap:install": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "7.0.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^7.0",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "7.0.*"
    }
}

I am not using nelmio security bundle, so why do I receive this message ?
I tried to modify my nelmio cors bundle without success.

Maybe it is a good idea to translate the error message to english. That way, more people can help you with this.

The error message translated is the following

Content-Security-Policy : The page settings have prevented the
execution of an embedded script (script-src-elem) because it
encounters the following directive: “script-src 'self'”.

In simple terms the CSP you have is preventing you from loading scripts from external domains.
When you see script-src 'self' in a CSP, it means that the page is only allowing JavaScript files to be loaded and executed if they are hosted on the same origin as the page, you will need to change your CSP for the external hosted scripts to load.
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP for more details
